# SQL query - need suggestion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am really confused how to write query for the following statement.

How to display top 5 employees with the highest number of sales (total) and display position as a field. Note that if both of employees have the same total sales values they should receive the same position, in other words Top 5 employees might return more than 5 employees?

Anyone can suggest an answer for this?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some database structure? And some data examples?

Comment: So if there are more than five employees in the top five rankings, how do you want to manage that? For example if you had one employee with 100 sales and then five employees with 90 and then one with 80, would you want all the first six in your "top five sales scores" list or would you want to drop one of the employees so you have a "top 5 sales people" list and if so what is your criteria for choosing who is dropped?

Comment: if more than one employees have the same total sales values i need to list all those employees to the "top five list".

Comment: So, you want the employess having a salary among the Top-5 salaries. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Rank() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC ) AS [Rank]
        , SUM(salary) as sum
        , Employee
    FROM 
        [table]
    GROUP BY
        Employee
)
SELECT  * 
FROM cte 
WHERE [RANK] < 5
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

I re-read your question and it seems that you're looking for the top count of sales rather than sum of salary, but of course, in that case you can just use `COUNT(sales)` in the OVER statement.